# Submit Business 2 Business Demo App

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, b2b

In order to properly understand the infrastructure and the tools of Apple's B2B (both for the "Seller" and the VPP User) - our organisation would like to set up our own Volume Purchase Program account and submit a "dummy" demo app using our existing iTunes Connect account that could be purchased using the new VPP account.

Do you think we'll have any issues with Apple reviewing this "dummy" application? I was thinking that in the "Notes" for review section we could add this comment that this application will be made available only for our own VPP account so we can better understand the infrastructure and the tools.

Is there any other approach to this besides just looking through available Apple documentation without actually using the platform?

Answer (score 1):

Just to help anyone coming to this post.

Apple does not let you publish B2B app until you have at least one VPP account. This VPP cannot be from the same organisation who is trying to sell that APP. In other words, Apple does not allow your organisation to be seller and purchaser both.

Apple will review your app, they will even ask you for login credential so that they can log in and review that app.

Do not mention anywhere in App that it is for demo or beta or alpha otherwise apple will not allow it to publish.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how dumb your dummy application is. They certainly won't let it pass if it's identifiably a test app. That's not what iTunes Connect is for. You can use TestFlight to distribute apps internally, without approval, and that's essentially the last phase of app experimentation before Apple will consider it built for the real world.

Potentially review why you need to test this process with a dummy app, and if there's a better method to achieve what you want.

Otherwise, write a basic utility app, (i.e. a clock app, or something similarly benign), and push that through.

In regards to testing the VPP process, it's similar to in-app purchasing; there's just no great way to do this nicely without going all the way.

You could approach it safest by developing a privately accessible app with a Paid Applications contract, although price your app as free.

See the Apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/B2B.html.